# Do you get DFS if you change the queue to a stack in a BFS implementation?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Here is the standard pseudocode for breadth first search:

```
{ seen(x) is false for all x at this point }
push(q, x0)
seen(x0) := true
while (!empty(q))
  x := pop(q)
  visit(x)
  for each y reachable from x by one edge
    if not seen(y)
      push(q, y)
      seen(y) := true
```

Here `push` and `pop` are assumed to be queue operations. But what if they are stack operations? Does the resulting algorithm visit vertices in depth-first order?

---

If you voted for the comment "this is trivial", I'd ask you to explain why it is trivial. I find the problem quite tricky.

Comment: I have seen students struggle with this, so I don't think it is strictly too simple. However, what more than "Yes" or "No" should an answer contain? The desired granularity is not clear from the question.

Comment: "Yes" would come with a convincing argument; "no" would come with a counterexample. But there are better answers than yes/no once you understand what's going on...

Comment: @Joe, Dave: please see the [ensuing meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-to-promote-inclusive-behavior)

Comment: It is possible to write pseudo-code so that simply by changing `pop` to a stack or a queue operation, we get dfs or bfs. It's also easy to write pseudo-code for which it at first appears that this is true, but it isn't.  http://www.ics.uci.edu//~eppstein/161/960215.html  is a relevant reference.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, this is not the same as a DFS.

Consider the graph

[image]

If you push the nodes in right to left order, the algorithm gives you a traversal:

$A, B , E, C , D$

while a DFS would expect it to be

$A,B,E,D,C$

The problem occurs because you mark it as seen at the time of pushing, rather than at the time of visiting. As pointed out in the comments, if you mark at the time of visiting, your space requirements might go up to $\Theta(V+E)$ rather than $\mathcal{O}(V)$.

I agree, the problem is not trivial.

Comment: This assumes that the adjacency lists have some fixed specific order. In mathematics at least, one views them as a set, and a graph has multiple depth-order traversals, depending on how you happen to iterate the children. (Imagine using hashes for children.) In that sense, ABECD is still a depth-first order. The questioner wonders whether there is a counter-example even in this setting. (Indeed, this is where it starts to get tricky.)

Comment: @rgrig: Well, this is one of the possible traversals, and that leads to a sequence which is not in DFS. No matter how you iterate, marking $D$ as seen will result in the DFS 'below' $E$ to come out wrong, if you don't visit $D$ first.

Comment: @Arybhata: Oh, sorry, I don't know why I was assuming that you meant for the edges to be directed and pointing downward. Their are undirected, so you are right: This is a counterexample even for what I was saying in the comment. (This is weird: I had to misspell your handle, so it doesn't get removed by SE.)